# Referencing an ArrayList Object from a different .aspx page it was created in

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist

I have an array list to which I add a list of codes. When I redirect to a different page(aspx) I want to be able to access these codes added to the arraylist from the other page.

Which is the easiest way to do this apart from creating a seperate Class.cs file.

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `Session` variables:

```
ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
//add items to arraylist
Session["MyArrayList"] = myArrayList;
```

And then simply switch it around on your second page to get it back:

```
ArrayList myArrayList = Session["MyArrayList"] as ArrayList;
//check to see if arraylist is null before using it
if (myArrayList != null)
{
    //array list is not null, safe to use
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `... = Session["MyArrayList"] as ArrayList;`. That way you don't throw errors if for some reason the session variable is empty. Users always like graceful error handling :).

Comment: What if some one use the previous page public property of Array List?

Comment: Sorry I'm not entirely sure what you mean.. Session state is unique per user, so each user could have their own copy of this ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to use Session, below code is recommended from my side :

Code for Page-1 from which you are redirecting to another page :

```
 System.Collections.ArrayList objArrayList = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
        objArrayList.Add("DEMO1");
        objArrayList.Add("DEMO2");
        Session["ArrayList"] = objArrayList;
```

Code for Page-2 on which you are redirecting from another page :

```
 System.Collections.ArrayList objArrayList1 = Session["ArrayList"] as System.Collections.ArrayList;
```

Comment: what about cross post back? Gaurav Rajput if previous page have public property of ArrayList??

Comment: @Abdul Majid: If i correctly understood your point then that scenario will go like this : Say there are two pages Page1 with a public property of ArrayList type and Page2. If we implement cross page posting from Page1 to Page2 then also this public ArrayList property will  be accessible on Page2 using syntax like PreviousPage._ArrayList. But for this we will be restricted to use Cross Page Posting.

Answer (score 1):

Even with a separate `class`, what you want can't happen directly (unless it is a static property). Each request your objects are being re-created.

The way around it is to store your `ArrayList` in the `Session`. See this MSDN link for details on Session State: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: It would be possible in a different class, when he uses static variables.